# Is Chechen language close to Chinese?

Tags: historical-linguistics, language-change, origin-of-language

If the both originate from Proto-Sino-Caucasian, then Chechen language should be close to Chinese. Is there any indication for this?

Comment: There's almost no evidence for Proto-Sino-Caucasian at all.

Comment: And even if there were, Chechen would **not** be close to Chinese.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **no**. For two reasons:

1. Just because a language might belong to the same family as another language, they may not be outwardly similar at all. Just compare German, Russian and Persian. It takes a very close historical study to link them. Or even just German and French.
2. Many of these proto-X families are extremely hypothetical and the evidence for them is tenuous and controversial based on a vague similarity of a few words, a few sound parallelisms and some proposed historical connection. Not infrequently being the pet theory of one author. Of these, Proto-Sino-Caucasian is one of the less widely accepted.

Answer (score -2):

I am Chechen and I speak Chinese as well. There are some words in both languages mutually understandable and spelled the same way - I guess that's ONE thing that (if it could) would made Chechen close to the Chinese.

The other thing is the tones, both in Chechen and Chinese.

I dunno how what methods the linguists use to refer one language to the other. I have noticed they (those who do so) do not even have a proper knowledge of Chinese/CHECHEN to be able to COMPARE them.

Comment: Aside from some informal remarks about some word resemblances and phonemic tone, your post amounts to an announcement that you don't have enough information to answer the question.   My advice is to research the issue.    These two links may help to get you started.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chechen_language   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_language   //   I know that you speak both languages, but knowing the languages and knowing about them are two different things.